# Can PHP session_start() in loop cause large response?

Tags: php, ajax, session, response

Using AJAX and PHP, I want to start a long-running PHP script via an AJAX request, and then using using another AJAX request get the progress of the long running script.  I have made a test script that simulates what I want.  The test as a whole "works" but the initial long-running script produces an error in the browser when it completes.  In Chrome I get a `net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TO_BIG` error.

Here is the offending code:

```
<?php

//Start a long-running process

$goal = 5000;
for($i = 0; $i < $goal; $i++) {
    session_start();  //Start/Reopen session to start/continue updating the progress
    if(!isset($_SESSION['progress'])) {
        $_SESSION['progress'] = $i;
        $_SESSION['goal'] = $goal;
    }
    //wait a wink
    usleep(rand(500, 2000));
    $_SESSION['progress'] = $i;
    session_write_close();  //Close session to gain access to progress from update script
}

?>
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the session being restarted so many times, but I would like some advice.  I need to restart the session because I am closing it at the end of the loop to gain access to the session info on another script.

Again, when I put this in with my test, things appear to complete, but I would like to solve the problem that is producing the browser error.  I can't reliably test for a successful AJAX request if browser returns an error.  Is there a way to limit how much header information PHP can send?

Comment: Open Firebug and check out the actual headers. If the headers are really repeated in stead of being replaced by PHP then yes, the headers might get very big and browsers might refuse to handle them.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Good call. Firebug confirmed that the PHPSESSID was being sent over a ton of times.  Oddly enough, Firefox had no issues with the response size.

Comment: Some things are standardized and some are not. Perhaps the maximum size of the headers is not standardized as part of the HTTP standard so it becomes an implementation detail in the knowledgeable of a (you guessed it) random developer dude. So Google Chrome decided it's MAX_HEADER_LENGTH will be 2^16, and Mozilla Firefox decided it'll be 2^32. Potato / potato.

Comment: I experienced something similar when I was using PrestaShop -- who keeps all of their session info inside an encrypted cookie. I was modding the software to transport something like ~500 pieces of product customization information. I eventually reached the MAX_COOKIE_LENGTH limit of some random browser. I had to alter the Session class PrestaShop was using to make it use `$_SESSION` in stead of `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably cookie header generated with every `session_start`. It's quite a hack, but you may try calling `header_remove();` after each `session_start();`.

Comment: The whole thing is quite a hack. We've already established we're selling ourselves cheap, the question is what's the price :D.

Comment: :) I once stored progress in database, so session storage needn't to be abused (can't say the same about db :)

Comment: A Redis key with increment would be more appropriate -- if you've got Redis. Or even Memcached but you don't have an increment op just get/set.

Comment: That worked beautifully.  After additional debug, it was the PHPSESSID being resent for each `session_start()`

Comment: @Crackertastic also you might want to move usleep after session_write_close - should increase overall smoothness of other parts of your app (increased time window when session is accessible).

Answer (score 0):

Why open and close all the time?
Just move the session start outside your loop.
I allways put it on top of my file :)

Comment: Reread the question -- he needs to close it to gain access to to session info on another script.

Comment: I can't do that because then my session variables won't be updated after calling `session_write_close()`

Comment: In that case i would prolly use: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.shmop.php.
instead of a session